# Fiddler keyboard shortcut to resume all breakpoints

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, fiddler

Is there a keyboard shortcut in Fiddler to resume all breakpoints? It seems like a pretty common operation that one would want to have a shortcut for.

I didn't see anything [on the fiddler website](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/keyboard.asp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no single key-combo for the "Resume all" button on the toolbar. But you can get close: hit **<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>** to set focus to QuickExec. Type **g** or **go** and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.